# Create an array of objects using the class generated by Core Data in XCode 8

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm struggling a little with how XCode 8 and Swift 3 manage classes in Core Data.

I have an entity that I've created, called `PersonMO` (the 'MO' standing for 'Model Object'). My understanding is that building my project after creating this entity results in a Class Definition being created elsewhere.

If I try to create an array of objects using that class definition, I get an error.

```
var people:[PersonMO] = [
    PersonMO(age:"24", firstName: "Cassie", isVisited: false, lastName: "Brist", locationCity: "San Francisco", locationState: "CA", notes: "none", phoneNumber: "000-0000", zone: "9")
]
```

The error is "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'PersonMO' with an argument list of type 'arguments listed here'", which makes sense because I never initialized the `people` array with default values.

Prior to XCode 8 and Swift 3, I had a `Person.swift` file that I initialized my values in, but now that XCode creates the class elsewhere, if I try to initialize in that file, I get an "Invalid redeclaration of 'PersonMO'" error.

How can I create a hard-coded array of objects in XCode 8 and Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has got nothing to do with generated classes. To create a `NSManagedObject` (assuming you have a ready setup `NSPersistentContainer`):

```
var people:[PersonMO] = []
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (moc: NSManagedObjectContext) in     

    //create new MO
    let newPersonMo = PersonMO(context: moc)

    // set attributes  
    newPersonMo.name = "Peter"

    //add it to your array
    people.append(newPersonMo)

    //save 
    do {
        try newPersonMo.managedObjectContext?.save()
    } catch {                    
        print("failed to save with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

---

Independent of your issue, you can choose if and what Xcode is creating for your entities whithin your Models Inspector:

I recommend to set `CodeGen` to `Class Definition`.

**Note:** to make this work without issues (I assume an Apple bug), the `Module` field has to be empty ("Global namespace" in light gray).
[image]

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for @shallowThought! I might instead do a preload using a CSV file, but this is a very useful thing to know for the future (I'm very new to programming so I'm often at a total loss as to how all the pieces interact).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 10, there is now [`NSManagedObject.init(context:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-initwithcontext) initializer you can use, instead of `init(entity:insertInto:)`. It's an extension that Apple has created for simplifying object creation. But you still need to use this initializer instead of your own.

---

The designated initializer of managed objects is `init(entity:insertInto:)`. You should not be initializing managed objects using different initializers.

From Apple's documentation:

> A managed object is associated with an entity description (an instance of `NSEntityDescription`) that provides metadata about the object (including the name of the entity that the object represents and the names of its attributes and relationships) and with a managed object context that tracks changes to the object graph. It is important that a managed object is properly configured for use with Core Data. If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (`init(entity:insertInto:)`).

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Leo. You're saying that, in order to create an array of objects built from the `PersonMO` class generated by Core Data, I need to use `init(entity:insertInto:)`? Where should I perform the initialization, given that the `PersonMO` class isn't accessible from the project navigator?

Comment: It's best to use `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)`. What we did was create a category over `NSManagedObject`, which automated this (entity name for us is the same as the class name) - but we still need to provide a context. We called the method `insertNewObjectInto(context:)`.

Comment: You do not need all of this any-more since Swift3/Xcode8

Comment: @shallowThought What does that even mean? What do the language (Swift 3) and the IDE (Xcode) have to do with the framework (Core Data)?

Comment: Sorry for being short. Work todo...Since iOS10 and Xcode8 would be correct. You do not need entity name, EntityDesccription an all the messy boilerplate anymore. I ceremonially  burned all those extensions, Core Data stacks and such. A rough overview can be found in this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/

Comment: Interesting. https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-initwithcontext Apple has not updated their documentation.